# Get the recent N records from a very huge database in oracle

Tags: performance, oracle

I am working on a very large Oracle database with around 90 million records. An I wanted to get the recent 100 records for the UI purpose. I was trying to achieve this using order by clause on the date column in the schema, even though I am able to get the recent records but it takes around 20-25 mints for the processing.

E.g. Schema

```
message_id varchar2,
message_head varchar2,
message_body varchar2,
----------
----------
message_date date
```

I was using the message_date to sort for the recent messages.

Could anyone please help me out to provide the latest 300 messages in less time (say less than 1 minute) And i am also wondering how big data-driven companies like facebook and twitter manages to give the latest posts and tweets within seconds.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Create an index on message_date
2) Add a sequence column (that is indexed also) and retrieve the last X records using that column

Note that if you're working on a 'live' database that the last X records is changing all the time.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am working on a live database. Actually i wanted the most recent messages depends on message_date ,if we use sequence number what happens a recent record getting added after particular time ?  Could you please elaborate little more ?

Comment: Sequence is always going to be return the most recent X records, so, in a live DB you'll always get the most recent while losing the ability to be specific (re: time).  If you use the date as a search criteria (last X records backwards from a certain date value) you can be more precise in what you request.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, or maybe even complementary...

Use optimizer mode hint for FIRST N ROWS. That will instruct the optimizer to optimize for a fast retrieval of the first records.

SELECT /*+ FIRST_ROWS(10) */ employee_id, last_name, salary, job_id
FROM employees
WHERE department_id = 20;

will optimize for retrieving the 10 first rows. You should do 100.